# Jackson Java generic parameter

Tags: java, rest, jackson, dto

I want to provide a DTO to use in a Jackson REST endpoint which has a generic parameter.

But I get this error when building.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:1.3.6:process (default) on project metrics-server: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown parameterized type: T. Available types in this context: {V=null, K=java.lang.String}. -> [Help 1]

public class ValidationRequest<T> {

    private final Map<String, T> columnValues;

    @JsonCreator
    public ValidationRequest @JsonProperty("columnValues") Map<String, T> columnValues) {

    this.columnValues = columnValues;
    }
}
```

My usage looks like this:

```
    Map<String, Double> testColumnValue = new HashMap<>();
    testColumnValue.put("sum", 1.0);

    ValidationRequest validationRequest = new ValidationRequest(columnValues);
    user.validate(validationRequest);  // this is a REST request

Can anyone help me figure out if this is possible?


Here is the stack trace:
[ERROR] execute error
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown parameterized type: T. Available types in this context: {V=null, K=java.lang.String}.
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:553)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.executeWithExceptionsHandled(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:248)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown parameterized type: T. Available types in this context: {V=null, K=java.lang.String}.
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.getDeclaredTypeForTypeVariable(AnnotationProcessor.java:711)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.visitTypeVariable(AnnotationProcessor.java:694)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.visitTypeVariable(AnnotationProcessor.java:461)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$TypeVar.accept(Type.java:1337)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.acceptOrRecurse(AnnotationProcessor.java:566)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.visitDeclared(AnnotationProcessor.java:543)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.visitDeclared(AnnotationProcessor.java:461)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:944)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.jsonTypeForDeclaredType(AnnotationProcessor.java:418)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.access$300(AnnotationProcessor.java:63)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.recurseForJsonType(AnnotationProcessor.java:667)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.addFieldFromBeanMethod(AnnotationProcessor.java:646)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.buildTypeContents(AnnotationProcessor.java:616)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.buildType(AnnotationProcessor.java:575)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.visitDeclared(AnnotationProcessor.java:560)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor$TypeVisitorImpl.visitDeclared(AnnotationProcessor.java:461)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:944)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.jsonTypeForDeclaredType(AnnotationProcessor.java:418)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.jsonTypeFromTypeMirror(AnnotationProcessor.java:391)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.buildRequestBody(AnnotationProcessor.java:288)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.buildRequestBodies(AnnotationProcessor.java:284)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.buildParameterData(AnnotationProcessor.java:254)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.processRequestMappingMethod(AnnotationProcessor.java:233)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.processElements(AnnotationProcessor.java:126)
    at org.versly.rest.wsdoc.AnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessor.java:87)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    ... 26 more
```

I have changed the name of the constructor in the original post, I hope this is a clearer example.

Comment: Don't use raw types. ValidationRequest is a generic type. So validationRequest should be of type ValidationRequest<Double>, not ValidationRequest. And you should program to interfaces: Map, not HashMap. Finally, when you ask about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code.

Comment: Making that change where the DTO is consumed in the DTO did not fix the issue.  I added the stack trace to the OP.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your comment. All I know is that the code you posted wouldn't compile, and that you haven't apply any of the changes I suggested. Now, at least, we know that the problem happens during the build, and is caused by versly (which I know nothing about), which you should add to your tags.

Comment: My original question is how do I use a generic parameter in a Jackson DTO and if I am doing that correctly using the code I provided, if now then how do I do this?

Comment: Why don't you read my first comment? It answers that question. Don't use raw types. Program to interfaces.

Comment: Replaced HashMap with Map and used ValidationRequest<Double>, everywhere but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with unit test that shows you made some effort. Your code makes no sense to me, due to several reasons:

1. Your code WILL NOT compile - You've some unknown type `InfluxValidationRequest` inside the class `ValidationRequest` which looks like a constructor but isn't.
2. There's a thing called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so a `Map<String, Double>` is just a raw `Map` at runtime.
3. Why not have different instances of the validator that knows how to validate a `Double` value, an `Integer` value, and so on? Where is the so-called validation code?

Comment: Sorry, I changed InfluxValidationRequest to ValidationRequest, typo. I was hoping to do this using one DTO with a generic type in the Map.   This is part of a much larger service and would be difficult to post enough to compile.

Comment: @mrmannione "I was hoping to do this" - What's this? Other than a POJO, there's not much in your question saying what are you trying to do. And if you can't take time to reproduce a smaller example, I don't think I can help you by looking at the minimal code.